# Improve plotting performance in Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I often have plots that are quite demanding which contain thousands of points (100k). I use ggplot, and Rstudio struggles to display them. I tried to export to png so I can view it, and that causes R to crash. Is there a way to improve the performance? I am thinking of something along the line of allowing Rstudio to access more RAM for plotting.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.2
```

PS: I rolled back all previous edits that insisted that this is an R not Rstudio problem. So for precision, I tested the plot in R: it takes time (30 seconds) but R plots it, it does not freeze like in RSTUDIO, and it does not crash. I saved as RDS the ggplot object and it came out to be 7.1 MB. The object has 7 layers and the structure of the data is as follows:

```
> pg <- ggplot_build(p)
> str(pg$data)
List of 7
 $ :'data.frame':   137596 obs. of  8 variables:
  ..$ colour  : chr [1:137596] "#7CAE00" "#7CAE00" "#7CAE00" "#7CAE00" ...
  ..$ y       : num [1:137596] 218 218 218 218 218 ...
  ..$ x       : num [1:137596] 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 ...
  ..$ PANEL   : int [1:137596] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ group   : atomic [1:137596] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "n")= int 2
  ..$ size    : num [1:137596] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 ...
  ..$ linetype: num [1:137596] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ alpha   : logi [1:137596] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ :'data.frame':   31036 obs. of  10 variables:
  ..$ y     : num [1:31036] 218 218 218 218 217 ...
  ..$ x     : num [1:31036] 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 ...
  ..$ PANEL : int [1:31036] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ group : int [1:31036] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
  ..$ shape : num [1:31036] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
  ..$ colour: chr [1:31036] "black" "black" "black" "black" ...
  ..$ size  : num [1:31036] 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 ...
  ..$ fill  : logi [1:31036] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ alpha : num [1:31036] 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 ...
  ..$ stroke: num [1:31036] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   1625 obs. of  10 variables:
  ..$ size  : num [1:1625] 2.63 2.03 3.46 6.4 2.31 ...
  ..$ colour: chr [1:1625] "#00BFC4" "#00BFC4" "#C77CFF" "#00BFC4" ...
  ..$ shape : num [1:1625] 16 16 17 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 ...
  ..$ y     : num [1:1625] 219 219 219 219 219 219 219 219 219 219 ...
  ..$ x     : num [1:1625] 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 ...
  ..$ PANEL : int [1:1625] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ group : atomic [1:1625] 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "n")= int 2
  ..$ fill  : logi [1:1625] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ alpha : num [1:1625] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
  ..$ stroke: num [1:1625] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ xintercept: num [1:2] 1.46e+09 1.46e+09
  ..$ PANEL     : int [1:2] 1 1
  ..$ group     : int [1:2] -1 -1
  ..$ colour    : chr [1:2] "black" "black"
  ..$ size      : num [1:2] 1 1
  ..$ linetype  : chr [1:2] "longdash" "longdash"
  ..$ alpha     : logi [1:2] NA NA
 $ :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  14 variables:
  ..$ y         : num [1:2] 206 206
  ..$ x         : num [1:2] 1.46e+09 1.46e+09
  ..$ PANEL     : int [1:2] 1 1
  ..$ group     : int [1:2] -1 -1
  ..$ colour    : chr [1:2] "black" "black"
  ..$ size      : num [1:2] 3.88 3.88
  ..$ angle     : num [1:2] 0 0
  ..$ hjust     : num [1:2] 0.5 0.5
  ..$ vjust     : num [1:2] 0.5 0.5
  ..$ alpha     : logi [1:2] NA NA
  ..$ family    : chr [1:2] "" ""
  ..$ fontface  : num [1:2] 1 1
  ..$ lineheight: num [1:2] 1.2 1.2
  ..$ label     : chr [1:2] "Algo start" "Algo Canceled"
 $ :'data.frame':   17 obs. of  8 variables:
  ..$ y       : num [1:17] 219 219 215 214 215 ...
  ..$ x       : num [1:17] 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 ...
  ..$ PANEL   : int [1:17] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ group   : int [1:17] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
  ..$ colour  : chr [1:17] "red" "red" "red" "red" ...
  ..$ size    : num [1:17] 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 ...
  ..$ linetype: chr [1:17] "dashed" "dashed" "dashed" "dashed" ...
  ..$ alpha   : logi [1:17] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ :'data.frame':   171 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ ymin    : num [1:171] -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf ...
  ..$ ymax    : num [1:171] Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf ...
  ..$ xmin    : num [1:171] 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 ...
  ..$ xmax    : num [1:171] 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 ...
  ..$ PANEL   : int [1:171] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ group   : int [1:171] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
  ..$ colour  : logi [1:171] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ fill    : chr [1:171] "blue" "blue" "blue" "blue" ...
  ..$ size    : num [1:171] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
  ..$ linetype: num [1:171] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ alpha   : num [1:171] 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 ...
```

Comment: R will take all the RAM it can get. If the plotting still crashes, reduce the number of points by subsampling your data. That’s unfortunately it. RStudio doesn’t really come into the picture at all.

Comment: Thousands of points shouldn't be a problem, how big is RAM? Maybe pre-plotting processes are eating up the memory. Share example data and plot code?

Comment: @zx8754: it's more like 270000 points - see above. RAM = 16GB. R takes 3-400 MB.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: My R session takes 400 MB. Which I think is very low, given that I have 16GB on my machine.

Comment: @Courvoisier Indeed, 400 MiB isn't a lot. Are you sure plotting directly to a file crashes in RStudio but not in R itself? That would be extremely weird, and in fact a bug in Rstudio. Unfortunately they don't make it easy to report bugs…. At any rate, there's little you can do. Subsampling the points would still be a good idea though.

Comment: Just tested with 300K points and 10 layers, output to png using ggsave on `RStudio Version 1.0.136`, all done in about 45 seconds. `ggplot2_2.2.1`

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yes, I just tried them again. I have two sessions running at the same time.

Comment: @zx8754: I tried (several times) to use the export option in RSTUDIO and that caused it to crash even though it wasn't displaying, as I thought it was a display option. I am now trying ggsave as png in both sessions and it has been a few minutes and still nothing.
It could be the types of layers that might be causing the issue. I will attach the layers structures if the sessions get liberated.

Comment: Apart from the technical challenge, showing that many points in one or a set of plots is not going to be visible. A smarter solution will be to subsample the data, or do some kind of aggregation. For example, a scatter plot can be aggregated by averaging over a hexagon grid put over the 2D plane (see `?geom_hex`).

Comment: @Courvoisier Uh, but "export" is something completely different from rendering directly to a file, that's why I asked specifically. I'm not surprised (though it's still a bug) that Rstudio is crashing when you try to export a plot that failed to render.